# Compare elements of a vector and choose elements from vector to be eliminated in a data set

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, statistics

My aim is to eliminate dupliccation in dataframe

i wrote a program that determine variables that have the same values in row 17 , next the program put these variables in other data and calculate correlation matrix , i set percentage of this correlation matrix to be 95% it means the program create vector that contain only variables names that correlated more than 95%

for example vector contain name of variables

```
>Vector

"MT91" "MT92" "MT93"
```

i want to use this vector to calculate the sum of these variables in all the other lines

for example i have this data :

Name

```
                           MT91           MT93           MT92         MT95
QC_G1                      70027.02132    95774.1359     100         24                  
QC_G2                      69578.18634    81479.29575    200         45
QC_G3                      69578.18634    87021.95427    10          42545
QC_G4                      68231.14338    95558.76738    1000        425
QC_G5                      64874.12936    96780.77245    7000        4545
QC_G6                      63866.65780    91854.35304    19          455
Ctr1                       66954.38799   128861.36163    199         2424
Ctr2                       97352.55229   101353.25927    155         344
Ctr3                       61252.42545   115683.73755    188         3434
Bti1                       81873.96379   112164.14229    1222        444
Bti2                       84981.21914   0.00000         100         3443  
Bti3                       36629.02462   124806.49101    188         3434
Bti4                       0.00000       109927.26425    122         1000
rt                         13.90181      13.90586        12          13
```

So i want to use the vector to calculate the sum of each variables in all the rows except the 17th row , after that i want to keep only the variable that have the highest sum,
as you can see it's my vector contain the variables : "MT91" "MT92" "MT93" and it's MT93 that have the highest sum in the 16 rows so i want to eliminate MT91 and MT92

The result will be :

```
                             MT93           MT95
QC_G1                    95774.1359           24                  
QC_G2                    81479.29575          45
QC_G3                    87021.95427        42545
QC_G4                    95558.76738         425
QC_G5                    96780.77245        4545
QC_G6                    91854.35304         455
Ctr1                     128861.36163       2424
Ctr2                     101353.25927        344
Ctr3                     115683.73755       3434
Bti1                     112164.14229        444
Bti2                     0.00000            3443  
Bti3                     124806.49101       3434
Bti4                     109927.26425       1000
rt                          13.90586          13
```

Note that the vector is generated by the program that will generate a lot of vectors (i'm using for loops) so i don't know the length of the vectors neither the name of the variables in the loops

Please tell me if you want any clarification
Thank you

Comment: Could you add `dput(data)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the follwing:

```r
#library
library(tidyverse)

# example data
tibble(name=LETTERS[1:17],
       a=c(1:17),
       b=c(2:18),
       c=c(3:19)) -> df

df
#> # A tibble: 17 x 4
#>    name      a     b     c
#>    <chr> <int> <int> <int>
#>  1 A         1     2     3
#>  2 B         2     3     4
#>  3 C         3     4     5
#>  4 D         4     5     6
#>  5 E         5     6     7
#>  6 F         6     7     8
#>  7 G         7     8     9
#>  8 H         8     9    10
#>  9 I         9    10    11
#> 10 J        10    11    12
#> 11 K        11    12    13
#> 12 L        12    13    14
#> 13 M        13    14    15
#> 14 N        14    15    16
#> 15 O        15    16    17
#> 16 P        16    17    18
#> 17 Q        17    18    19

# example vector
vector <- c("a","b")


# solution
df %>%                 
   dplyr::select(all_of(vector)) %>% # select vector items
   slice(-17) %>% # remove 17 line
   map_dbl(sum) %>% # make sum
   which.max() %>% # select max
   names() -> selected # select max name


df %>% 
  dplyr::select(!vector,selected) # select columns
#> # A tibble: 17 x 3
#>    name      c     b
#>    <chr> <int> <int>
#>  1 A         3     2
#>  2 B         4     3
#>  3 C         5     4
#>  4 D         6     5
#>  5 E         7     6
#>  6 F         8     7
#>  7 G         9     8
#>  8 H        10     9
#>  9 I        11    10
#> 10 J        12    11
#> 11 K        13    12
#> 12 L        14    13
#> 13 M        15    14
#> 14 N        16    15
#> 15 O        17    16
#> 16 P        18    17
#> 17 Q        19    18
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>